# Fierz idendity (supersymmetry)

Tags: definition, conventions, fermions, spinors, grassmann-numbers

So basically I have two Fierz identities involving spinors:

$$\psi^a \psi^b = -\frac{1}{2} \epsilon^{ab} \psi \psi$$

And

$$\overline{\psi}^{\dot{a}} \overline{\psi}^{\dot{b}} = \frac{1}{2} \epsilon^{\dot{a} \dot{b}} \overline{\psi} \overline{\psi}$$

The first one is immediate to solve it: The expression is antisymmetric, and therefore

$$\psi^a \psi^b = c \epsilon^{ab}.$$

But $$\psi \psi = \psi^a \epsilon_{ab} \psi^b = c \epsilon^{ab} \epsilon_{ab} = -2 c.$$

So  $$\psi^a \psi^b = -\frac{1}{2} \epsilon^{ab} \psi \psi.$$

The second one is the problem. Certainly, I am missing something in the definition. Using the same logic as above, we have

$$ \overline{\psi}^{\dot{a}} \overline{\psi}^{\dot{b}} = c \epsilon^{\dot{a} \dot{b}}.$$

So $$\overline{\psi} \overline{\psi} = \overline{\psi}_{\dot{a}} \overline{\psi}^{\dot{a}} = \overline{\psi}^{\dot{b}} \epsilon_{\dot{b} \dot{a}} \overline{\psi}^{\dot{a}} = c \epsilon_{\dot{b} \dot{a}} \epsilon^{\dot{b} \dot{a}}.$$

Obtaining $$ c = -\frac{1}{2} \overline{\psi} \overline{\psi}.$$

But this is *not* the second Fierz identity! What am I missing?

Comment: I can't remember the exact details, but I think for $\psi$, the inner product is defined as $\psi^2 \equiv \psi_a \psi^a$. For ${\bar \psi}$ the inner product is defined by ${\bar \psi}^2 \equiv {\bar \psi}^a {\bar \psi}_a = -  {\bar \psi}_a {\bar \psi}^a$. The reason for this sign is that, with these definitions, we have $( \psi^2 )^* = {\bar \psi}^2$

Comment: @Prahar I am sorry, can you be a little more detailed? I really can't see what i did wrong

Comment: Is this from a reference? Which page?

Comment: @LSS - The definition of $\psi \psi$ and ${\bar \psi} {\bar \psi}$ should differ by a sign.

Comment: @Prahar This is so confuse. The right-hand definition of dot product isnt upstairs? As i wrote (with the dot over the index)

Comment: My point is that we DEFINE $\psi \chi \equiv \psi^a \chi_a$ and we deifne ${\bar \psi} {\bar \chi} \equiv {\bar \psi}_a {\bar \chi}^a$. This is simply a definition.

Comment: @Prahar This is what i am saying. If we start by this definition, as i did, we got the wrong answer, and i don't know why. You started in the commend from a different definition ($\overline{\psi}^a \overline{\psi}_a$), so it is not clear to me where i made a mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We define
\begin{align}
\psi \chi &\equiv \psi_a \chi^a = - \epsilon_{ab} \psi^a \chi^b , \qquad {\bar \psi} {\bar \chi} \equiv {\bar \psi}^{\dot a} {\bar \chi}_{\dot a} =  \epsilon_{{\dot a}{\dot b}} {\bar \psi}^{\dot a} {\bar \chi}^{\dot b} . 
\end{align}
Expanding the sum out explicitly and find
$$
\psi \psi  = - 2 \psi^1 \psi^2 , \qquad {\bar \psi} {\bar \psi} = 2 {\bar \psi}^{\dot 1} {\bar \psi}^{\dot 2} . \tag{1}
$$
We have
$$
\psi^a \psi^b = c_1 \epsilon^{ab} \psi \psi  , \qquad {\bar \psi}^{\dot a} {\bar \psi}^{\dot b} = c_2 \epsilon^{{\dot a}{\dot b}} {\bar \psi} {\bar \psi} 
$$
For some constants $c_1$ and $c_2$.

We can now set $ab={\dot a}{\dot b}=12$ in the equation above and using $\epsilon^{12} = \epsilon^{{\dot 1}{\dot 2}} = 1$, and matching to (1), we find
$$
c_1 = - \frac{1}{2} , \qquad c_2 = \frac{1}{2}.
$$